# Hwmon PWM-fan driver missing from Raspberry pi version of Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: drivers, fan

Is there any reason why the hwmon pwm-fan driver is omitted from the raspberry pi version on Ubuntu 22.04. It’s inclusion would allow the control of raspberry pi PWM fans using suitable dtoverlays rather than having to use user land code and software PWM.

Comment: If you don't get the answer you need here there is also a [RasberryPi specific Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) that might know more

Comment: What are you using for hardware?  The PI doesn't have PWM headers.  It's also a completely different architecture, ARM vs x86.  There isn't just one PWM driver, but many drivers depending on the chips on the motherboard, none of which are on a PI.

Comment: The PI has hardware PWM on the GPIO pins, others have got a PWM fan working using the GPIO pins with a dtoverlay for the PWM-fan driver.Be cause it isn’t included in the main distribution, it means compiling your own kerneto include itl, which is OK for a development environment, but not so good for a production system.

Comment: Are you saying the drivers are on Raspbian?

Comment: I don’t know about Raspbian, but the same issue exists on RaspberryPi OS 64bit version, you have to compile your own kernel to include the PWM-fan driver and then use a dtoverlay to customise it to to work with a gpio PWM fan.